# Правильно ли реализована проверка аргументов метода на корректность и бросание исключения

Tags: java, исключения, методы

Есть метод заполняющий массив данными :

```
public Double[] fill(Double[] array) {
    return checkNonNullArray(array) ? Arrays.stream(array)
                                                    .mapToDouble(value -> GeneratorDataRandomDouble.generateDouble())
                                                    .boxed()
                                                    .toArray(Double[]::new)
                                            : new Double[DEFAULT_SIZE_ARRAY];
}
```

Метод checkNonNullArray() реализован следующим образом :

```
public static boolean checkNonNullArray(Number[] array) {
    if (nonNull(array)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The reference to the array passed to the method is \"null\".");
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, корректна ли такая проверка на null и такая работа с исключением в методе checkNonNullArray() ?
Также подскажите, правильно ли реализовано возвращаемое значение в методе fill() ?

Если будет перед массив за значением null, то будет брошено исключение и выполнение потока закончится. И значит созданный массив с размером DEFAULT_SIZE_ARRAY не будет возвращен методом.

Возможно лучше реализовать метод таки образом.

```
public Double[] fill(Double[] array) {
  if (checkNonNullArray(array)) {
     return Arrays.stream(array)
                  .mapToDouble(value -> GeneratorDataRandomDouble.generateDouble())
                  .boxed()
                  .toArray(Double[]::new)
    }   
}
```

Comment: А что за метод `nonNull()`? Что он делает?

Comment: Вообще не очень понятно, что вы хотите  получить. Если на входе `null`, то вернуть массив, заполненный  `null`, а если не `null`, то заполненный случайными значениями? Или исключение должно обрабатываться где-то за пределами этого кода, в тех методах, откуда это вызывается? Тут одно из двух -- или генерируем исключение, или что-то возвращаем. В случае генерации исключения никакое значение не возвращается.

Comment: И есть такое ощущение, что вы сильно всё переусложнили.

Comment: Метод nonNull() - это метод класса Objects, просто импортирован с помощью import static. Он выполняет проверку на null. Возможно Вы правы с тем, что я что-то сильно перемудрил. ))) Я немного переделал код, добавив своеобразный массив по-умолчанию, заполненный нулями и размерностью 5 элементов. Он 
возвращается если аргументом передан массив со значением null. Смысл всего кода заключается в том, чтобы вынести проверку на корректность в отдельный класс со статическим контекстом. Просто в классе заполняющим массивы значениями, много перегруженых методов и проверки повторяются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам не надо исключения ловить где-то в вызывающем коде, а надо при вызове с некорректным параметром просто вернуть массив, заполненный нулями, то может быть, проще сделать так:

```
public Double[] fill(Double[] array) {
    Double[] dd = new Double[array == null? DEFAULT_SIZE_ARRAY: array.length];
    if (array != null) 
        for (int i = 0; i < dd.length; i++) 
            dd[i] = GeneratorDataRandomDouble.generateDouble();
    return dd;
}
```

Я, честно говоря, не понял, какая экономия получается от вынесения проверки в отдельный метод с генерацией там исключения и добавления блока `try ... catch` в метод, заполняющий массив.

`Objects.nonNull()` я тоже не вижу смысла здесь использовать. Он обычно используется в качестве предиката в фильтрах.

Answer (score 1):

Некорректно то, что у вас исключение нигде не обрабатывается. Надо где-то обработчик исключения прописать, например так:

```
public static boolean checkNonNullArray(Number[] array) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (nonNull(array)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The reference to the array passed to the method is \"null\".");
    }
}

public Double[] fill(Double[] array) {
    try {
        if (checkNonNullArray(array)) {
            return Arrays.stream(array)
                .mapToDouble(value -> GeneratorDataRandomDouble.generateDouble())
                .boxed()
                .toArray(Double[]::new);
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Double[DEFAULT_SIZE_ARRAY];
}
```

Comment: А то что метод checkNonNullArray() объявляет в сигнатуре unchecked исключение : throws IllegalArgumentException . Это ничего?

Comment: Если выполнять обработку исключения при вызове  метода fill()?

Comment: Да, уже прописал. Спасибо.

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, я просто думал, что желательно только checked исключения добавлять в сигнатуру метода через throws, но можно и unchecked или не жалетельно?

Comment: Даже так. А я почему, то думал наоборот. Но допустим, не нужно вызывать throw new ... checked исключение, а нужно его обрабатывать. А вот если unchecked, то можно вызывать, throw new ... unchecked exception ?

Comment: Какой смысл выносить генерацию исключения в отдельный метод, и тут же его ловить и обрабатывать? Только для того, чтобы распечатать стек? тогда проще `if (array == null) new Ecxeption("сообщение").printStackTrace()`